# Get the Name of the Variable which holds the instance of a function, inside this the function,

Tags: javascript

Umm i didnt knew a better title,
I wonder if there is a way to do sth. like this:

```
function myFunc() {
    //do some Stuff...
   this.myMethod = function(x) {
    //do some more Stuff
    var nameofthevariable = myVar//somehow get the Variables name
    myVar.somePropertie = "SomeOtherStuff";
   }
}
myVar = new myFunc();
myVar.myMethod(x)
```

- Is there a way to get the Name or the Var itself from inside the function, which instance it holds ?
  So i can put back the Data, the method creates into the variable, without passing it as argument to the function or method =)

Thanks for any answers

## Answer

Thanks for the Answer =), ah thats sad
The Problem with `this`is that I have an Object,
a Propertie of the Object creates an Instance of `myFunc` and executes `myMethod()`
this should add a new Propertie to `myObj`, so i have the Output from `myMethod` seperated from the instance of `myFunc()`

```
function myFunc() {
    //do some Stuff...
   this.myMethod = function(x) {
    //do some more Stuff
    var nameofthevariable = myObj//somehow get the Variables name
    myObj.somePropertie = "SomeOtherStuff";
   //and here i could do
   this.Parent.somePropertie = "SomeOtherStuff";
   }
}
myObj = {}
myObj.myProp = new myFunc();
//i could do:
myObj.myProp.Parent = myObj
//
myObj.myProp.myMethod(x)
```

But then i could pass `myObj`, as an Parameter to the `myMethod` too
I wanted to go Up to the Object i want to add sth, twice with the getting of the Variable Name,

I think, `this`won't work in that context, as i cant access variables of an level higher than the instance of `myFunction`

### Your Edit

Oh yes, thanks =) in the real Code its a 'privileged' function and i can call the method,
I'll edit it in the Question,
Thanks for pointing that out, i didnt even realize that when writing this in the question here.
It works well except that i dont find a way, dynamically putting back the Data to the Object which holds the Instance"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get the name of the variable, but you seem to be asking how `myMethod()` can add a property to `myVar` where `myVar` is the instance of `myFunc` that `myMethod()` was called on - in which case using `this` will work:

```
function myFunc() {
    //do some Stuff...
   this.myMethod = function(x) {
      //do some more Stuff
      this.somePropertie = "SomeOtherStuff";
   }
}
myVar = new myFunc();
myVar.myMethod(x)
```

Note that the way you had defined `myMethod()` it was a private function accessible only from within `myFunc()` - to call it with the `myVar.myMethod()` syntax you need to make it a property (so I've changed that bit too).

The value of `this` within a function depends how the function was called. When you call `myFunc()` with the `new` operator JS sets `this` to the newly created instance. When you call a method with the `myVar.myMethod()` "dot" syntax JS sets `this` to `myVar`.

For more information about `this` I'd suggest reading [the MDN `this` article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i Updated the Question =)

[+1] and accepted as it answers the Question whether its Possible to get the name =)

Comment: I don't believe you can get the current object's parent, and note that it might have multiple parents: `myObj={}; myObj.myProp = new myFunc(); myOtherObj = myObj.myProp; myThird={myProp:myOtherObj}; myThird.myProp.myFunc();`

Comment: Ah, so i have to pass it as an argument to whichObject the Output is added, or set the Parent as an propertie.  

Yes it can have multiple Parents, but shouldn't be there only one   Parent Object to which the Propertie originally was added,   
in that case 'myObj', would be nice if there were anythin which   woukld then Point from e.g `myThird.myProp.oinstance //myObj` or sth else like this

Comment: The thing is that JS doesn't really have "child objects", what it has is a property on the "parent" that refers to the "child" but there are no restrictions on other variables and/or properties of other objects referring to that same "child". To take my above example a step further, if you said `myObj.myProp = null` you'd find that `myThird.myProp` still refers to the "child" object...

Comment: K thanks =)
that makes sense,  
 guess then i'll just let the method return all the data and i set it like  
`myObj.outputdata = myObj.myProp(x)`